# WepApi post parameters are null

Tags: jqgrid, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to WebApi and I have problem with the received post parameters.
I want to populate jqgrid with data received from webapi controller method.

The grid code is as follows:

```
buildPostData: function (postData) {

            var parameters = {
                page: postData.page,
                rows: postData.rows,
                sidx: '',
                sord: '',
                _search: false,
                searchField: '',
                searchString: '',
                searchOper: '',
                filter: { groupOp: '', rules: [] }
            };

            $.extend(parameters, postData);

            var data = {
                parameters: parameters
            };

            return JSON.stringify(data);
        }

bindGridAllData: function () {

            var viewModel = this;

            jQuery("#AllDataGrid").jqGrid({
                url: 'api/DataApi/GetAllData',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'POST',
                ajaxGridOptions: {
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                },
                serializeGridData: viewModel.buildPostData,
                serializeRowData: function (data) {
                    return JSON.stringify(data);
                },
                jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, root: "d.rows", page: "d.page", total: "d.total", records: "d.records" },
                colNames: ['DataId', 'Title', 'Description', 'Date', 'UserId', 'Name', 'Surname', 'PicturePath', 'NumberOfComments', ''],
                colModel: [
                        { name: 'DataId', index: 'DataId', width: 10, hidden: true, editable: false, sortable: false, key: true },
                        { name: 'Title', index: 'Title', width: 10, editable: false, align: 'left', sortable: true, hidden: true },
                        { name: 'Description', index: 'Description', width: 10, editable: false, align: 'left', sortable: true, hidden: true },
                        { name: 'Date', index: 'Date', width: 10, editable: false, align: 'left', sortable: true, hidden: true },
                        { name: 'UserId', index: 'UserId', width: 10, editable: false, align: 'left', sortable: true, hidden: true },
                        { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 10, editable: false, align: 'left', sortable: true, hidden: true },
                        { name: 'Surname', index: 'Surname', width: 10, editable: false, align: 'left', sortable: true, hidden: true },
                        { name: 'PicturePath', index: 'PicturePath', width: 10, editable: false, align: 'left', sortable: true, hidden: true },
                        { name: 'NumberOfComments', index: 'NumberOfComments', width: 10, editable: false, align: 'left', sortable: true, hidden: true },
                        {
                            name: 'DataInformation', index: 'DataInformation', width: 200, editable: false, align: 'left', sortable: true, formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                                var template = $('<div data-bind="template: { name: \'DataRecord\', data: DataRecord, ajax: { async: false } }"></div>');
                                var data = { DataRecord: rowObject };
                                ko.applyBindings(data, template[0]);

                                return template.html();
                            }
                        }
                ],
                height: '100%',
                width: 900,
                pager: '#resultGridAllDataPager',
                rowNum: 10,
                rownumbers: false,
                scroll: false,
                sortname: 'Date',
                sortorder: "asc",
                gridview: true,
                hoverrows: false,
                viewrecords: true,
                cmTemplate: { title: false },
                loadComplete: function () {
                }
            });
        }
```

And the WebApi method is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JQGridData GetAllData(JQGridSearchParameters parameters)
    {
        using (dataMKbazaEntities context = new dataMKbazaEntities())
        {
            JQGridData grid = new JQGridData();

            var allData = context.ispolniSITEpodatoci().ToList();

            List<object> data = new List<object>();

            foreach (var ad in allData)
            {
                data.Add(new {
                    DataId=ad.podatokID,
                    Title=ad.naslov,
                    Description=ad.opis,
                    Date=ad.datum,
                    UserId=ad.idKORISNIK,
                    Name=ad.ime,
                    Surname=ad.prezime,
                    PicturePath=ad.slika,
                    NumberOfComments=ad.brojKOMENTARI
                });
            }

            grid.rows = data;
            grid.page = parameters.page;
            grid.records = data.Count;
            grid.total = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)data.Count / (float)parameters.rows);

            return grid;
        }
    }
```

When sending data, parameters have values defined from `buildPostData` method but when received in WepApi controller method they are null.

I have tried with `[FromBody]` in webapi method but with no success.
Status code in http request is 200 OK

Comment: Why you using `POST` for getting the data? Isn't `GET` is the right way?

Comment: Yes but I want to use POST because I don't want the data that is sent to be in the query string

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any sense in usage of `buildPostData` function. Why you need to place all parameters which you want to send to `GetAllData` inside of object with property `parameters`? Why you don't use just `return JSON.stringify(postData);` directly? You don't included definition of `JQGridSearchParameters` so one can't full answer on your question. In any way I recommend you to read [the blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx) which describe two main ways of biding of data Model Binding and Formatters.

Comment: I don't see additionally that you use `parameters` inside of `GetAllData`. I see no sorting, paging or filtering of data in the server code. Probably you can just better use `loadonce: true`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure of the following:

1. Your raw request has the Content-Type header. Looking at your client code you seem to be sending it, but just wanted to make sure that it is indeed sent over the wire. Web API had a bug where if you do not send Content-Type header, since we do not know which formatter to deserialize the content, we default to the default value of the C# type. In this case it could be 'null'. This has been fixed later and is not yet publicly available though.
2. Have the following check to see any model state errors:

   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
               throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, this.ModelState));
   }